# how to run windows java executable that have extension .exe on linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, jar, reverse-engineering

i have .exe file, that file is java executable, how i can run it into linux system, "wine" is not working, i can do open it file with 7zip file manager and it is archive that contains some of java *.class files. But have not contain the *.jar file.

Is it possible to run this program under Linux?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the major reasons not to create `.exe` Java executives. The solution is to create a jar file with your Java code and run that on Windows **or** Linux **or** Mac. If this is not your code, then the solution is to contact the developer or distributor for their jar files.

Comment: yes, it is not my code, I'm not sure that the developer wants to make a jar file.

Comment: @IvanIvanovich: there's only one way to find out. Otherwise unless you can make sense from the `.java` files you have access to, you're sunk.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Wine HQ](https://www.winehq.org/) , i use it for a lot of .exe's that i want to run on my Linux machine and it never dissapointed me :)

Comment: this is not the way that I need I'm trying to run the game that written in java and compiled under windows if i will run it under wine, then i need to install the java under wine.

Comment: But it is not faster than windows, in this case I do not get a performance advantage from running in Linux